# What does "post-production" mean?

Tags: meaning, word-usage

[Pudget Systems](http://www.pugetsystems.com/genesis.php) has a computer called Genesis:

> A cutting edge, highly reliable workstation optimized for
>   post-production and design.

What exactly does *post-production* mean in this sentence?

Comment: [post-production](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/post--production?q=post+production)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post-production):

> "[Post-production] is a term for all stages of production occurring
>   after the actual end of shooting and/or recording the completed work."

In this context it mainly consists of video editing and adding visual/special effects. These tasks require highly powerful machines.